# Godot 3.5: Web Build using custom GDNative C++ Library does not work due to `dlopen` error and failed linking

Tags: c++, web, export, godot-3

### The Problem

Currently I am trying to get the official GDNative C++ example for Godot 3.5, which can be found [here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-cpp/tree/3.5) working in the Web Export context. So far, I managed to export to X11.64 without any troubles and managed to set up the creation pipeline for the Web Assembly (see section "Web Assembly Creation Process" below), which now produces a valid output without any error messages. However, as soon as I try to run the game in any browser, it stops loading and displays the following error message:

```
Aborted(To use dlopen, you need enable dynamic linking, 
see https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/wiki/Linking)
```

This link only contains a link to the new documentation of `emscripten`, which is used to create the Web Assembly file, and is at the time of writing located at https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/Dynamic-Linking.html.

### Final File Structure

```
ROOT/
  ├─godot-project-src/
  |   └─lib/
  |      ├─wasm/
  |      |   └─libsimple.wasm
  |      ├─SimpleLibrary.gdnlib
  |      └─SimpleLibrary.gdns
  └─SimpleLibrary/
      ├─godot-cpp/
      |    ├─bin/
      |    |  └─libgodot-cpp.javascript.release.wasm.a
      |    ├─include/
      |    |   ├─core/
      |    |   └─gen/
      |    └─godot-headers/
      ├─bin/
      |  └─libsimple.wasm
      └─src/
         └─init.cpp
```

### Web Assembly Creation and Export Process

#### At the beginning of the project (only necessary once):

1. Initialize `SimpleLibrary` directory with `godot-cpp` and `godot-headers`.
2. Create the release JavaScript Godot Binding via 
   `scons platform=javascript generate_bindings=yes target=release`,
   which creates the archive `SimpleLibrary/godot-cpp/bin/libgodot-cpp.javascript.release.wasm.a`.
3. Create GDNative Import Files in the Godot Project Directory.

   ```
    godot-project-src/lib/SimpleLibrary.gdnlib
    godot-project-src/lib/SimpleLibrary.gdns
   ```

#### After each change:

1. Create the new Web Assembly Library

   ```
    cd SimpleLibrary
    emcc -o bin/libsimple.wasm -g -O3 -sSIDE_MODULE=1 src/init.cpp godot-cpp/bin/libgodot-cpp.javascript.release.wasm.a -Igodot-cpp/include -Igodot-cpp/include/core -Igodot-cpp/include/gen -Igodot-cpp/godot-headers
   ```
2. Copy the newly created library to the correct location in the Godot Project Folder

```
   cp bin/libsimple.wasm ../godot-project-src/lib/wasm
```

3. Update (if necessary) the GDNative Import Files in the Godot Project Directory.

   ```
    godot-project-src/lib/SimpleLibrary.gdnlib
    godot-project-src/lib/SimpleLibrary.gdns
   ```

#### Web Export

Just selecting the HTML Export Template via the Godot Editor, choosing the Export Folder and let Godot do its thing.

### Questions

1. Did I miss some necessary settings during the Web Assembly creation? I already had to change some compiler flags for `emcc`and add include directories compared to the original example to get it even to compile. I also experimented with the optimization flags, the deprecated `-shared` flag, `-sDYNAMIC_EXECUTION`, `-sMAIN_MODULE`, but no changes.
2. Do I have to create a custom HTML Export Template for this to work properly? According to the GDNative Documentation, if

```
   godot-project-src/lib/SimpleLibrary.gdnlib
   godot-project-src/lib/SimpleLibrary.gdns
```

are created properly, this should not be necessary.

3. Is the GDNative C++ Web Export at all possible? During my research, I only found very vague documentation, a lot of (not really related) github issues and more questions than answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some detailed checking of the `emcc` compiler flags and verifying their functionality in the documentation, I realized that the Godot Webexport does not produce the files required for the pseudo-shared library approach of `emcc`. After taking a close look at the official Godot 3.5 Documentation regarding [Web Export Options](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/tutorials/export/exporting_for_web.html#export-options), I found that I missed to set one property in the Godot HTML Export Template Settings.
[image: Godot HTML Export Template Settings: Default]

The documentation states clearly that for GDNative to work in the Web Export, the `Export Type` has to be set to `GDNative`.
[image: Godot HTML Export Template Settings: Required]

Now the Godot HTML Export includes the three according to the `emcc` documentation required `.wasm` files:

1. The library itself `libsimple.wasm`,
2. The side-loading library `<PROJECT EXPORT NAME>.side.wasm`,
3. The main `.wasm` containing the default Godot functionality `<PROJECT EXPORT NAME>.wasm`.